# Travis fails by my rspec testfile - local not

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I have written some test examples for rspec in [my project](https://github.com/saigkill/youtube_dlhelper).

On my local machine all tests passing. But the [travis check](https://travis-ci.org/saigkill/youtube_dlhelper/jobs/16390861) failes. It says:

```
Failures:
  1) Transcoding Checker should converts a file from Youtube
     Failure/Error: YoutubeDlhelperLibs::Ripper.rip("#{@tempfile}")
     Errno::ENOENT:
       No such file or directory - the file 'Crystallize___Lindsey_Stirling__Dubstep_Violin_Original_Song_.m4a' does not exist
     # ./lib/youtube_dlhelper/libs.rb:114:in `new'
     # ./lib/youtube_dlhelper/libs.rb:114:in `rip'
     # ./spec/lib_spec.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  2) Cleanup Routine Should cleanup all downloaded and generated files
     Failure/Error: File.delete("#{@tempfile}.mp4")
     Errno::ENOENT:
       No such file or directory - Crystallize___Lindsey_Stirling__Dubstep_Violin_Original_Song_.mp4
     # ./spec/lib_spec.rb:50:in `delete'
     # ./spec/lib_spec.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The relevant code is in my libs_spec.rb:

```
require 'rspec'
require 'dir'
require 'fileutils2'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/spec_helper'
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib'))
require 'youtube_dlhelper/libs'
@tempfile = 'Crystallize___Lindsey_Stirling__Dubstep_Violin_Original_Song_'    

      describe 'Transcoding Checker' do
      it 'should converts a file from Youtube' do
        puts 'Entering Test: Transcoding Checker'
        @tempfile = 'Crystallize___Lindsey_Stirling__Dubstep_Violin_Original_Song_'
        YoutubeDlhelperLibs::Ripper.rip("#{@tempfile}")
        File.exists?("#{@tempfile}.mp3")
        puts 'Test passed...'
      end
    end

    describe 'Cleanup Routine' do
      it 'Should cleanup all downloaded and generated files' do
        require 'fileutils2'
        @tempfile = 'Crystallize___Lindsey_Stirling__Dubstep_Violin_Original_Song_'
        File.delete("#{@tempfile}.mp4")
        File.delete("#{@tempfile}.m4a")
        File.delete("#{@tempfile}.mp3")
      end
```

And the used methods in my libs:

```
module Ripper
    # Methode for transcoding the *.m4a file to *.mp3. Output should be a valid MP3 file.
    def self.rip(filename)
      require 'streamio-ffmpeg'
      puts 'Initializing the file'
      movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new("#{filename}.m4a")
      puts 'Initializing finished'
      movie.valid?
      puts 'Validated'
      movie.transcode("#{filename}.m4a", "-acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 192k #{filename}.mp3")
      puts 'Transcoded'
    end
```

Has anyone an idea why?

Comment: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Comment: Looks like some problem with expecting files or paths to be same on Travis as you have locally. Tin Man's quote is relevant, please don't just post links on SO asking for help on your project with all the details off-site. If you want help, you need to put effort in to composing the question, so relevant details are easy to see. Most volunteers on SO will not chase down your code just so they can help you, and also this makes a poor question for later searching - adding the error message from Travis would be useful.

Comment: I have updated the post. Can we un-hold it now please?

Comment: Voted to reopen. Could you clarify where the input file `Crystallize___Lindsey_Stirling__Dubstep_Violin_Original_Song_.m4a` is in your project? I don't see it on github . . . how are you copying it to Travis?

Comment: The module Downloader before downloads a Crystallize___Lindsey_Stirling__Dubstep_Violin_Original_Song_.mp4 and extracts the music into a .m4a.

Comment: It seems that in fact it does not: `Entering Check: Download Checker
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.9.1, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.8
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.9.1, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.8
Audiofile not found: Crystallize___Lindsey_Stirling__Dubstep_Violin_Original_Song_.m4a
Videofile not found: Crystallize___Lindsey_Stirling__Dubstep_Violin_Original_Song_.mp4
Test passed...` - your test is still "passing" because you do not make any assertions - why all the `puts` and no `should` or `expect` methods?

Comment: What can i make better? This was my first excourse in testing an app.

Comment: Instead of the conditions and `puts` statements, use an RSpec matcher with `expect` or `should`. E.g. `File.exists?("#{@tempfile}.mp3").should be_true`  Try reading through this tutorial for the correct syntax, and notice the differences with your test scripts: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/ruby-for-newbies-testing-with-rspec/

Comment: The problem is fixed now. I changed the access of viddl-rb from 'viddl-rb' to system("viddl-rb" "parameters"). Now it works.